Define interface based on array type
Given:
const qualities = ["beauty", "cost", "upkeep"] as const
export type QualityStrings = (typeof qualities)[number]

I make use of QualityStrings outside, it cannot be discarded.
I also need an interface like the following:
export interface QualitiesInterface {
    beauty: number
    cost: number
    upkeep: number
}

as I'm implementing and extending the interface elsewhere.
But this is not DRY, I'm repeating myself. Would it be possible to define the same interface with mapped types?
export interface QualitiesInterface {
    [???]: number
} 

I can define those keys dynamically in a type but don't know how to do the same for an interface:
type QualitiesType = {
    [V in QualityStrings]: number
}


Why does it need to be an interface? The type works fine.

because i need to implement the interface elsewhere, a class cannot implement a type AFAIK

A class can't extend a type or interface, it can only extend a value. It can implements either, though: https://tsplay.dev/N9D2jw

It's not clear to me why you need this. You can always write interface QualitiesType extends Record<QualityStrings, number> {} but the use case you mention doesn't require an interface, you can write class Foo implements Bar {} as long as Bar is a named type with statically known keys. Bar can be a type alias, doesn't matter. What should we do with this question to proceed?

i didnt think to add that i need to extend the interface also (edited the question to fix that). @jcalz your comment is the answer though, if you make it one here i will accept it :)

What you need is Record<..., ...> I believe.
So, in this case it could be rewritten as:
export interface QualitiesInterface extends Record<QualityStrings, number> {}

Basically we're 'converting' type to interface above with the use of extension semantics:
interface SomeThing extends MyType {
   // normal iface stuff can be added here if needed
}

